# Scary film where a woman has vaginal teeth

Tags: story-identification, movie

I started watching this film late at night a few years ago. UK.
I suddenly leaped up and grabbed the remote and switched it off.

This woman was setting off to have sex with a bloke and the viewpoint switched to inside her, there was snarling noises and rows of teeth in her vagina waiting to bite him.

I found it disturbing and went to bed (nerves jangled all night!).

Comment: Don't know why I'm getting a down vote...I did try a Google first but I kept getting stuff about vampires

Comment: _Teeth_ is the first Google result I receive when I search for "vagina teeth movie".  Please note this is not the short of thing I typically search for.

Comment: I was 'scaredy cat' to put vagina into Google so I was just doing 'woman with sharp teeth'

Comment: Don't ever be afraid to use medically correct vocabulary.  We're all adults here.  If the answer is correct then please mark it so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is probably [*Teeth*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0780622/) (2007). Not a good film, but it does match your description.

From IMDB:

> Still a stranger to her own body, a high school student discovers she has a physical advantage when she becomes the object of male violence.

Answer (score 10):

This trope has a TvTropes page named [Vagina Dentata](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/VaginaDentata), which translates by itself. And it cites the "most obvious example of all" to be [*Teeth*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0780622/) (2007).

> Dawn grows up in the shadow of a nuclear power plant. In high school, while her biology class studies evolution, she realizes she may have a hidden curse, an "adaptation." She lives with her mom, step-father, and hard-edged step-brother. She likes Tobey, a guy at school, and he likes her. She takes a pledge to remain chaste until marriage, so they date in groups, watch G-rated films, and don't kiss, but the power of teen hormones is great, so temptation beckons. Dawn has an admirer in Ryan, and when when things have an unexpected twist with Tobey, she turns to Ryan for help. Will he be her mythical hero and rescue her? Or can she find her way as her own hero, turning the curse into an asset?

The trailer is not *that* unsafe for work, but I'm guessing the movie might be...

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like the 2007 horror comedy [Teeth](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0780622/)

> Dawn (Jess Weixler) is an active member of her high-school chastity club but, when she meets Tobey (Hale Appleman), nature takes its course, and the pair answer the call. They suddenly learn she is a living example of the vagina dentata myth, when the encounter takes a grisly turn.